# using fork repo in google colab

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to change models in torchvision models to add an argument to be able to vary the size of the model.
So I made a fork of the pytorch/vision repo, where I changed the code in a model.
Then cloned the changed repo  from my github (in google colab). But I am struggling to access the cloned repo:
When simply trying:
from vision import torchvision as new_tv
it gets the already existing vision package from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision instead of the new changed vision.

How can I access my new cloned repo module vision (preferably without replacing the actual torchvision)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git or GitHub. You just need to set up your Python path correctly to point to whatever version you want Python to import. You may use Git (or not) to create your own private version, and import from there. Note that for self-sanity and other reasons **it's a good idea to change the name of the package** (but it's not required and sometimes that's painful to do).

Comment: Changing the name of the package to vision2 and importing it, somehow still leads to the use of the unchanged model (wrong path for the model)... How can I specify from where I want to import exactly? Or could there be another reason for why vision2.torchvision.models still gets the model from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py?

Comment: Python `from <foo> import <bar>` means *using <foo> as the search path for modules, do an import and call it <bar>* so be sure you're using `from vision2 import ...`. See the Python documentation about module search paths as well (this varies depending on Python version but `PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path` plays a big role).